# SQL Server: Logical equivalent of ALL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a following query (simplified):

```
SELECT
    Id
FROM
    dbo.Entity
WHERE
    1 = ALL (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN {Condition} THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
        FROM
            dbo.Related
            INNER JOIN dbo.Entity AS TargetEntity ON
                TargetEntity.Id = Related.TargetId
        WHERE
            Related.SourceId = Entity.Id
    )
```

where `{Condition}` is a complex dynamic condition on `TargetEntity`.

In simple terms, this query should return entities for which all related entities match the required condition.

Unfortunately, that does not work quite well, since by SQL standard `1 = ALL` evaluates to `TRUE` when `ALL` is applied to an empty set. I know I can add `AND EXISTS`, but that will require me to repeat the whole subquery, which, I am certain, will cause problems for performance.

How should I rewrite the query to achieve the result I need (SQL Server 2008)?

Thanks in advance.

**Note**: practically speaking, the whole query is highly dynamic, so the perfect solution would be to rewrite only `1 = ALL ( ... )`, since changing top-level select can cause problems when additional conditions are added to top-level where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you use a min to achieve this?

EG:

```
SELECT
    Id
FROM
    dbo.Entity
WHERE
    1 = (
        SELECT
            MIN(CASE
                WHEN {Condition} THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END)
        FROM
            dbo.Related
            INNER JOIN dbo.Entity AS TargetEntity ON
                TargetEntity.Id = Related.TargetId
        WHERE
            Related.SourceId = Entity.Id
    )
```

The min should return null if there's no clauses, 1 if they're all 1 and 0 if there's any 0's, and comparing to 1 should only be true for 1.

Answer (score 0):

It can be translated to `pick Entities where no related entities with unmatched condition exist`.

This can be accomplished by:

```
SELECT
    Id
FROM
    dbo.Entity
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
//as far as I have an element which do not match the condition, skip this entity
        SELECT TOP 1 1
        FROM
            dbo.Related
            INNER JOIN dbo.Entity AS TargetEntity ON
                TargetEntity.Id = Related.TargetId
        WHERE
            Related.SourceId = Entity.Id AND
            CASE
                WHEN {Condition} THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END = 0
    )
```

*EDIT*: depending on condition, you can write something like:
`WHERE Related.SourceId = Entity.Id AND NOT {Condition}` if it doesn't change too much the complexity of the query.

Comment: I think if there are no related entities at all, NOT EXISTS will be TRUE here (which is the same problem that I am having with ALL).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `all`, change your query to compare the result of the subquery directly:

```
select Id
  from dbo.Entity
  where 1 = (
      select 
        case 
          when ... then 1
          else 0
        end
        from ...
        where ...
      )
```

Comment: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this will work: WHERE NOT 0 = ANY(...)

Comment: No, does not work for an empty set either. 0 = ANY return false for an empty set (which is expected), so NOT 0 = ANY returns TRUE, which is the same as 1 = ALL.

Answer (score 0):

If I read the query correctly, it can be simplified to something like:

```
SELECT       e.Id
FROM         dbo.Entity e
INNER JOIN   dbo.Related r ON r.SourceId = e.Id
INNER JOIN   dbo.Entity te ON te.Id = r.TargetId
WHERE        <extra where stuff>
GROUP BY     e.Id
HAVING       SUM(CASE WHEN {Condition} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*)
```

This says the Condition must be true for all rows.  It filters the "empty" set case away with the INNER JOINs.

Comment: This does work in the given case. However, see my note. There are situations when top-level where can contain two of such conditions, for example.

Comment: @Andrey Shchekin: This one supports WHERE as well (edited).  Anyway, fyjham's answer is pretty good